# li tag - make image smaller

Tags: html, css

I have trouble making the image on my li tag smaller, like 35x35px.

```
<ul>
  <li id="grund_brand"></li>
</ul>
```

my css

```
#grund_brand {
    list-style-image: url('/indhold/uddannelse/grund_brand.jpg');
}
```

the problem is: the picture is great but would like to have it down to 35x35 pixels.

I really can not remember what it takes to do this.

Comment: Why not use a 35x35 image to begin with?

Comment: because the image I need is not available online.

Comment: Most people would _create_ or _alter_ an existing image, upload it and use that. Image editors are not that scarce.

Comment: No, okay, it just might be that I should consider it in a different way then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution would be to use an image that is already the size you need.
But if you cant do that for whatever reason, try putting an image inside of the li, like so:

```
<ul>
  <li id="grund_brand"><img src="/indhold/uddannelse/grund_brand.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

and then use CSS to set the height and width of that image:

```
li img { height: 35px; width: 35px; }
```